# In Azure Dev, Joindomian error is coming while try to release build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, packer

I am getting the error

2020-08-25T13:35:27.2978114Z ##[error]VMExtensionProvisioningError: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'joindomain'. Error message: "Exception(s) occured while joining Domain '*******18gmail.onmicrosoft.com'"

And I am trying to build this custom image
https://github.com/Azure/RDS-Templates/blob/master/wvd-templates/Create%20and%20provision%20WVD%20host%20pool/mainTemplate.json

By following this blog and I am at the very last step
https://jrudlin.github.io/2019-09-02-windows-virtual-desktop-azure-devops-ci-cd-packer-build-and-release/#files

I have already created AD Domain controller add the domain ips in Virtual Network. But still it is showing this error. Can anyone please help me to resolve?

Comment: Hi Did you check out the documents in below answer. How is it going with this case now?

Answer (score 0):

The error can be caused by many reasons. You can [check the deployment history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=azure-portal) to view the detailed error information.

It could be the account and password provided for joining VMs to the domain are incorrect or the account doesnot has rights to add computers to the domain. It also could be the Domain name doesn't resolve. Or your virtual network (VNET) DNS configuration is set to Default. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/troubleshoot-set-up-issues%C2%A0#azure-resource-manager-template-errors) for more inforamtion.

There are more instructions  you can check in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/troubleshoot-vm-configuration#vms-are-not-joined-to-the-domain) to troubleshoot the issue of joining VMs to the domain.

Below are the similar issues that might be helpful for your troubleshooting.

[JoinDomain VMExtensionProvisioningError when deploying WVD](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-virtual-desktop/joindomain-vmextensionprovisioningerror-when-deploying-wvd/m-p/918716)

[“JoinDomain” Errors - When and Why They Happen](https://www.softwareone.com/en-ca/blog/articles/2020/05/13/noram_deploying-windows-virtual-desktop-host-pool-in-azure)

[JoinDomain / Conflict](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-virtual-desktop/joindomain-conflict/m-p/727866)

Hope above helps!

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Specify domain or unit" option or select NO while configuring session host. It creates the conflict between specified host name and VM own hostname.